# How would I extract information from multiple strings and input it into database as separate tables using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a log of over 200 of these identical lines of code below:

```
1/5/2016    6   5   8   0   6       1    
Offset  1  
1/4/2016    2   7   9   2   3       18   
Offset  4  
1/3/2016    2   1   7   4   7       14   
Offset  6
```

I would like to take the list above and with PHP extract each value and separately enter them into a database as follows:

Table 1:

```
- Date: 1/5/2016    
- Val1: 6   
- Val2: 5   
- Val3: 8   
- Val4: 0   
- Val5: 6       
- Val6: 1    
- Offset:  1
```

Table 2:

```
- Date: 1/4/2016    
- Val1: 2   
- Val2: 7   
- Val3: 9   
- Val4: 2   
- Val5: 3       
- Val6: 18   
- Offset:  4
```

And so on so forth, Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Sure. Did you look into/try anything?

Comment: Yes, I can find anything

Comment: @JoshTutt, you are just being lazy. At least give us a hint of anything you have tried, and where it is failing you. This will form a good basis for helping you. Look into the PHP explode() function and tell us how far you get - php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out! Here was my solution:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'test');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test#');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');
===
//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

$e = explode( 'X', $input1 );
foreach($e as $val) {
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $val, $matches);

$Date = $matches[0][0] . "/" . $matches[0][1] . "/" . $matches[0][2];
$Val1 = $matches[0][3];
$Val2 = $matches[0][4];
$Val3 = $matches[0][5];
$Val4 = $matches[0][6];
$Val5 = $matches[0][7];
$Val6 = $matches[0][8];
$MN = $matches[0][9];


$qry = "INSERT INTO PowerBall(Date, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5, Val6, MN) 
VALUES('$Date','$Val1','$Val2','$Val3','$Val4','$Val5','$Val6','$MN')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
```